# GitHub Action use file of other branch?

Tags: github-actions

The GitHub Action below performs two steps:

1. long.py fetches the data from an API and saves it but the data rarely changes
2. quick.py processes the saved data generated by long.py

```yaml
name: build

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 2 * * *'

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-python@v2
        with:
          python-version: '3.x'
          cache: 'pip'
      - run: |
            pip install -r requirements.crawl.txt
            python py/long.py
            python py/quick.py

      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@4.1.5
        with:
          branch: gh-pages
          folder: dist
```

I do not want to overuse the API in long.py, but I want to execute quick.py on every push, so I want to create another action with a push trigger that only performs quick.py.
However that won't work because the resulting file from long.py is not existing on the master branch but it lives on the gh-pages branch.
What is the easiest way to provide `quick.py` with the last saved state of `long.py` from the gh-pages branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to use caching:

https://github.com/actions/cache

You can use hash of your file as a key.